# How to configure the session to stop executing all following commands on first error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have a script:

```
alter table ....
go

insert into ...
go

alter table ...
go

delete from ..
go
```

How do I configure this session at the beginning of this script, so that if any of the four commands raises any error, all following commands in the script are skipped?

I don't want to do anything to these commands themselves, such as adding "raiseerror" and try/catch etc. All I want to do is to add something at the beginning of the script, so that the "abort on error" will happen automatically.

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2005? It ran *completely* out of support *almost* **7 years ago**; it is *long* past time getting that instance upgraded and doing so will be very difficult now.

Comment: As these are in separate batches, then you've defined that the next statement should be run regardless of the outcome of the last. They need to be in the same batch if you want that kind of behaviour.

Comment: I see - the "go" marks the end of a batch and multiple commands in the same batch shall be separated by semicolons. So, if I want the above four commands to abort on the first error, I shall separate them using semicolons instead of "go". Am I right?

Comment: Correct. You may need to also turn on `XACT_ABORT` on, however, I'm not sure if such an ancient and unsupported version allowed the sytnax.